# Reactjs development server won't start on macos catalina

Tags: node.js, reactjs, macos, create-react-app, fsevents

I am trying to create a new react.js project with create-react-app. When I execute `yarn start`, the development server doesn't start and the console gives me this message :

```
Starting the development server...

dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _FSEventStreamCreate
  Referenced from: /Users/username/project/node_modules/fsevents/build/Release/fse.node
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _FSEventStreamCreate
  Referenced from: /Users/username/project/node_modules/fsevents/build/Release/fse.node
  Expected in: flat namespace

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

That happens with the newly created react.js project, not with the older ones.
I install and reinstall node.js with `brew install node`, I also reinstall create-react-app, but nothing happens.

Information about my environment :

1. OS: macOS Catalina , version 10.15.4 (19E266)
2. Node : v13.11.0
3. create-react-app : version 3.4.1
4. yarn : version 1.22.4
5. npm : version 6.13.7

Thanks in advance for a perfect answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was repeated again . To solve it I just go to brew [website](https://brew.sh/index_fr) and copy the installer code `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"` then everything works again

Answer (score 2):

Deleting the fsevents folder/folders inside. 'node_modules' worked for me on MacOS Mojave. 
If after deleting one fsevent directory , it still fails , then delete the fsevents folder in the current path shown in the error.

Answer (score 2):

Deleted the fsevent folder inside the node_modules/webpack-dev-server worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me. MacOS Catalina 10.15.4. I basically deleted node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents and it started working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was getting a similar error, not while using React but while using Phoenix and Elixir. Since this question is one of the only search results for the error message `Symbol not found: _FSEventStreamCreate`, I'll share my problem and my solution:

I'm using MacOS Mojave 10.14.6 and was trying to create a Phoenix app using `Elixir 1.9.4 (compiled with Erlang/OTP 22)`, Phoenix `v1.4.10`. The problem was that live reloading was going haywire: my pages kept refreshing over and over even when I hadn't made any changes.

Looking in my server output I saw things like this repeated over and over:

```
[error] Task #PID<0.1149.0> started from RumblWeb.Endpoint terminating
** (stop) :watcher_command_error
    (phoenix) lib/phoenix/endpoint/watcher.ex:29: Phoenix.Endpoint.Watcher.watch/3
    (elixir) lib/task/supervised.ex:90: Task.Supervised.invoke_mfa/2
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:249: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Function: &Phoenix.Endpoint.Watcher.watch/3
    Args: ["node", ["node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js", "--mode", "development", "--watch-stdin"], [cd: "/Users/george/code/phoenix/programming_phx/rumbl/assets"]]

Webpack is watching the files…

...

dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _FSEventStreamCreate
  Referenced from: /Users/george/code/phoenix/programming_phx/rumbl/assets/node_modules/fsevents/build/Release/fse.node
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _FSEventStreamCreate
  Referenced from: /Users/george/code/phoenix/programming_phx/rumbl/assets/node_modules/fsevents/build/Release/fse.node
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

I.e. webpack was getting errors, causing the page to recompile and reload, but the source of those errors was something to do with `dyld` and `fsevents`.

I don't understand what the error means, but upgrading my version of `node` from `v12.10.0` to `v13.13.0` fixed it.

(Don't forget to restart the phoenix server, and make sure that the terminal window in which `mix phx.server` is running is using the new, updated version of node.)

Comment: Just a few days after posting this answer, I started getting the exact same error again. Turns out that a new version of Node (14.0.0) was released on April 21st. Upgrading Node again caused the error to go away again.

Comment: Argh, now the error is happening *again* and I have no idea why. See my comment on this GitHub issue: https://github.com/fsevents/fsevents/issues/313

Comment: Update: I still haven't fixed this. I'm not sure there is a fix until the next version of `webpack-dev-server` is released; see https://github.com/fsevents/fsevents/issues/325 and https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/pull/2539. However, the workaround I've come up with for Phoenix is to comment out the part `watchers: [ node: ... ]` from config/dev.exs. This means webpack will no longer watch the files, meaning you'll need to manually compile your assets every time you make a change - but it's the only way I've found for now to get around this frustrating issue.

Comment: I ran out of space in my previous comment, but just to add: to manually compile your assets on Phoenix you can run `cd assets && node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --mode development`.